# Is it possible to trigger a Javascript action through a HTaccess redirect?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with a lot of language subfolders /de/ /fr/ /es/ etc and I am using a combination of redirected/cached translation and uncached onthefly translation. I need the Cart areas of my site to be cached onthefly rather than redirected which it is at the moment. However, I'd like to be able to make the foreign language experience seamless so the customer doesnt have to click on the flag again once the translation type has changed. They'll be coming into the cart through /de/cart. As an example if I was a German customer I would be happily in the /de/ German subfolder with everything in my language but when I go to the cart, I get knocked back to English and have to click the flag again as the redirect has changed. My problem really is that I don't know how to trigger the translation without having a url to direct it to. I thought something like this might work:

`redirect 301 /de/cart http://www.my-site.com/cart?lang=de`

But this obviously does nothing because I don't know how to say to Google Translate I want to trigger this language. Thanks for taking the time to read this and any help would be greatly appreciated. It might in fact be impossible to achieve this in the way I am trying so a simple not possible would also help :-)

Comment: Please stop embedding google translate to your site at all. It's better to provide only an english version.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you can use Google Translate and edit the translations as you wish. It creates a good base for translations to begin with and there is no problem embedding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the javascript you have to parse `window.location` to find the `lang=de` and then take action based on the result.

However, it seems strange to me that you are using google translate on your page -- if you want localized versions write the code to do so -- google translate is an external tool and not a very good one compared to a true translation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've found that the Javascript I need to call is javascript:doTranslate('en|de');; but I'm aware that I can't just put in redirect 301 /de/cart http://www.my-site.com/cartjavascript:doTranslate('en|de');; Is there any way to call javascript through htaccess or would I have to do something else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is no way to call JavaScript on a target page from another page or htaccess -- the page itself has to do the function but you can pass in cookies or url arguments.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll work on creating a solution from those two options.